# find type -f also returns non-matching files in matching directory

Tags: linux, find

## all files/folders in current directory:

```
./color_a.txt   
./color_b.txt   
./color_c.txt   
./color/color_d.txt   
./color/blue.txt   
./color/red.txt   
./color/yellow.txt
```

## command used to find all files with the word *color* in name:

```
find ./*color* -type f
```

## result:

```
./color_a.txt   
./color_b.txt   
./color_c.txt   
./color/color_d.txt   
./color/blue.txt   
./color/red.txt   
./color/yellow.txt
```

## expected result:

```
./color_a.txt   
./color_b.txt   
./color_c.txt    
./color/color_d.txt
```

The result also includes all the non-matching file names under a matching parent directory.
How could I get ONLY files with names directly matching the *color* pattern?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want for filename filtering is a simple `-name <glob-pattern>` test:

```
find -name '*color*' -type f
```

From `man find`:

```
 -name pattern
        Base  of  file  name  (the  path with the leading directories removed) matches shell
        pattern pattern.  Because the leading directories are removed, the file names
        considered for a match with -name will never include a  slash,  so `-name a/b' will 
        never match anything (you probably need to use -path instead).
```

Just as a side note, when you wrote:

```
find ./*color* -type f
```

the shell expanded the (unquoted) glob pattern `./*color*`, and what was really executed (what `find` saw) was this:

```
find ./color ./color_a.txt ./color_b.txt ./color_c.txt -type f
```

thus producing a list of files in all of those locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **regex** option

```
find -regex ".*color_.*" -type f
```